# set contentDescription for tabLyaout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, accessibility

I want to set contentDescription for tabs of tabLayout but talkBack doesn't read the content description of the tab that is selected and it just say 'selected'. How do I have to set contentDescription for tabLayout?

I update content description in viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener for each tabs and also I tried to set content description in tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener for each tabs but none of them worked!

```
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    updateTabContentDescription();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
```

...

```
private void updateTabContentDescription() {
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            if (tab != null) {
                tab.setContentDescription(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

and I test it for viewPager:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    updateTabContentDescription();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: add some log in updateTabContentDescription and check

`private void updateTabContentDescription() {
        Log.d("test","in updateTabContentDescription");
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            if (tab != null) {
                Log.d("test","in updateTabContentDescription, desc:"+adapter.getPageTitle(i));
                tab.setContentDescription(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            }else{
                Log.d("test","in updateTabContentDescription,tab is null");
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: @App I do it.and it's result:D/test: in updateTabContentDescription
D/test: in updateTabContentDescription, desc:product
D/test: in updateTabContentDescription, desc:service

Comment: how you are reading content description of the tab

Comment: @App If I get your mean correctly , I turn on 'talkback' and 'display speech out' in developer settings  and then test it !

Comment: Just call the updateTabContentDescription(); after you initialize the viewpager, it does not have to be inside the OnPageChangeListener or OnTabSelectedListener